# MongoDB How to find and update data in a nested structure

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble with my mongoDB (v3.6.4), below is what my data looks like right now. I need to find (and update) the "text" value for a certain element in "second_list", i.e. return "hello" and change it to "hello world " in next step.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
  "top_list": [
    {
      "create_time": "2019-06-10 15:56:46",
      "second_list": [
        {
          "name": "v1",
          "text": "hello"
        },
        {
          "name": "v2",
          "text": "good morning"
        },
        {
          "name": "v3",
          "text": "bye"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i have tried this query

```
    db.myCollection.find(
            {'top_list.second_list.name':'v1'},
            {"top_list.second_list":1,"_id":0}
        )
```

but it returned the whole of "second_list". What i want should be

```
{
          "name": "v1",
          "text": "hello"
}
```

or just the string "hello".

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works for me to find and update a value

```js
db['myCollection'].findAndModify({query:{_id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")}, update: {$set: {"top_list.second_list.0.text":"someNewText"}}})
```

The 0 in `top_list.second_list.0.text` is the array index you're wanting to access

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb Has function Called [FindAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

and your query should be like this

and the $ array operators in this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/) will help to modify what you want

Like $elemmatch